# creating staging environment locally on single host using docker

Tags: docker

I need to recreate our staging environment locally on a single host machine to help with testing and development.

Our staging environment consists of

1. chef server,
2. redis server,
3. elastic search server.

I want to run each server in a separate container. And allow the containers to communicate with each other.

So I created a separate container for the chef server. And within that container I ran the bootstrapping script to install all the packages required for the chef server.

While running the bootstrapping script I encountered an error,

```
---- Begin output of /opt/chef-server/bin/chef-server-ctl start rabbitmq ----
STDOUT: warning: rabbitmq: unable to open supervise/ok: file does not exist
STDERR: 
---- End output of /opt/chef-server/bin/chef-server-ctl start rabbitmq ----
Ran /opt/chef-server/bin/chef-server-ctl start rabbitmq returned 1
```

The strategy is to first get the chef container running so that the chef container can provision the redis and elastic search containers. But I'm not even able to get the chef server running.

At this point I do not know how to proceed. Can someone please point in the right direction? I searched for a work around and couldn't find anything to help me.

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe if you can share how you create the chef container and the contents of the bootstrapping script it will be easier for others to help you out.

Comment: The chef container was created by creating a base ubuntu container. And then vim, git, wget and curl were installed manually. Downloaded our chef cookbook repo that we use in our production and ran the bootstrap script. The bootstrap script basically takes care of getting and installing the chef server and then hands over control to the "chef server application" to install the rest of the packages required for the "chef server container". If you need more details please do let me know. Thanks

Comment: If you just want to set up a number of containers and link them together, why not use fig? I've also written Docker Shell for the same purpose (where you get access to the docker client from inside a docker container). http://dockershell.io/

Answer (score 0):

It seems the issue has nothing to do with Docker:

https://tickets.opscode.com/browse/CHEF-3838